# Get the last X number of files in a directory

Tags: php

How can I get the last X number of files in a directory in PHP?

I use this code for getting the last file, but how I can get the last X number of files?

My code:

```
$path = "/path/test/"; 

$latest_ctime = 0;
$latest_filename = '';    

$d = dir($path);
while (false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
   $filepath = "{$path}/{$entry}";
   // could do also other checks than just checking whether the entry is a file
   if (is_file($filepath) && filectime($filepath) > $latest_ctime) {
      $latest_ctime = filectime($filepath);
       $latest_filename = $entry;
   }
}
```

Comment: What do u mean by last "X" file?

Comment: Get the last 10 file's for example

Comment: I updated your question to use *n* instead of *x*: feels more like an integer number.  Also made some minor grammar corrections.

Comment: Wow 30 lines over 3, that's amazing!

Comment: Rolled back edit as answers used `X` instead on `N` before edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$arr = array();
$path = "/Users/alokrajiv/Downloads/";
$d = dir($path);
if ($handle = opendir($path)) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            $filepath = "{$path}{$entry}";
            $tmp = array();
            $tmp[0] = $filepath;
            $tmp[1] = filemtime($tmp[0]);
            array_push($arr, $tmp);
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
function cmp($a, $b){
    $x = $a[1];
    $y = $b[1];
    if ($x == $y) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($x > $y) ? -1 : 1;
}
usort($arr, 'cmp');
$x = 10;
while(count($arr)>$x){
    array_pop($arr);
}
var_dump($arr); //has last modified 10 files
```

Sort in the descending order then pop till 10 elements are left.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Might be a little simpler:

```
$files  = array_filter(glob("$path/*.*"), 'is_file');
array_multisort(array_map('filectime', $files), SORT_DESC, $files);
$result = array_slice($files, 0, $x);
```

- Read all files with `glob()` and filter with `is_file()`
- Sort files on `filectime()` descending
- Slice the first (latest) `$x` number of files